# How to configure macOS-like text navigation shortcuts in ubuntu (delete word/line, move cursor by word/line)

Tags: keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys

I use a macOS for work doing technical writing, and I've recently got an Ubuntu desktop at home (20.04). I'm using the same external keyboard for both, and the biggest thing I struggle with is that I'm so used to using the following macOS hotkeys:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> - delete word on the left (I realize that this can be achieved by <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>, but I'd prefer if everything was the same across OSs)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> - move cursor one word left/right (including the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> combo to select&move)
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Backspce</kbd> - delete line left
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> - move cursor to start/end of line (including the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> combo to select&move)

Whenever I have to use a Windows machine, I reconfigure it using AutoHotkey to give the macOS-like shortcuts. is there an equivalent way that I can adjust these settings on a system-wide basis for Ubuntu?

I would like this to apply across ALL apps, including terminals, browsers, system software, etc if possible.

I don't have the full autohotkey script available, but here is one I threw together so people can see what I'm going for:

```
; alt-backspace becomes delete-word-left
!Backspace::
Send, ^{Backspace}
return

; ctrl-backspace becomes delete-line-left
^Backspace::
Send, {Shift Home Backspace}
return

; ctrl-left becomes "home"
^Left::
Send, {Home}
return

; ctrl-right becomes "end"
^Right::
Send, {End}
return
```

(and no, Vim is not an option :) )

Comment: Can you paste into your answer your configuration for autohotkey? That would give a better understanding what is an acceptable workaround for you.

Comment: Where do you mean to have those key bindings available?
At the command line?
In a specific application?

Answer (score 2):

I have mapped my capslock to escape. I used xmodmap for this..
**Step 1 :** Identify the keycodes for the keys you want mapped using xev. Run xev and press the keys you want mapped to get their key codes, like so : 
 `xev | grep -i keycode` 
 *I am unsure of the key behaviour in macOs, so apologies, you will need to try this out yourself.*
**Step 2 :** With the keycodes you have, use the xmodmap -e to try out if your key mapping works as you would like. 
 For instance : 
*`#This is to map CapsLock to Esc`* 
`xmodmap -e 'keycode 66 = Escape'`

 If you want to get your old key layout back in the middle of this testing step, you can use 
`setxkbmap -layout us`
**Step 3 :** Once you have all your keycodes, put them in a file in your home directory(or anywhere accessible by your user on login) For instance my final xmodmap file looks like so : 
`keycode 66 = Caps_Lock`
`keycode 9 = Escape`
`remove Lock = Caps_Lock`
`add Lock = Escape`
`keycode 9 = Caps_Lock`
`keycode 66 = Escape`

**Step 4 :**  Modify your ~/.xinitrc to run xmodmap on startup with the custom keybindings. Mine is like so : 
`/usr/bin/xmodmap ~/.speed`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`xmodmap`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap), which is deemed appropriate "for the simplest tasks",
or the more recent and comprehensive [XKB](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_keyboard_extension) (see also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_keyboard_extension)).
It is often quoted that you should avoid the old `xmodmap` in favor of `xkb`.
(and "Note: Due to a limitation of Xorg, xmodmap settings are not applied to hotplugged devices automatically. If a keyboard is added to a system after a custom table has been applied, the custom table will have to be applied again.")

To find the raw keycodes, you would use `xev`, [same as for `xmodmap`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382842/how-to-find-the-raw-keycodes-for-xkb).

As for how to get the specific bindings you mean to, you would probably have to dig a little deeper into `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h` and the output of `man xkeyboard-config`.

And you can also [get an `xkb` configuration from `xmodmap`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202883/create-xkb-configuration-from-xmodmap).

See also

https://www.charvolant.org/doug/xkb/html/node5.html

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205226/xkb-make-ctrlbackspace-behave-as-delete

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/504158/permanently-change-xkb-keybindings

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28993/what-is-bashs-meta-key

https://medium.com/@damko/a-simple-humble-but-comprehensive-guide-to-xkb-for-linux-6f1ad5e13450

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions

Comment: thanks sancho. this seems like a better utility and seems to gell well with x11